# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.5 in Intellij. Within a Java project it worked perfectly. The problems arose when I tried to bring my Java sources into a Java Enterprise project, with a Web Application template and using Tomcat 9.0.46. If I try to instantiate an object that makes use of Hibernate, it gives me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry     at
> database.LibroDBWrapper.findByTitoloAutore(LibroDBWrapper.java:115)
> at database.LibroDBWrapper.(LibroDBWrapper.java:77)   at
> entity.Libro.(Libro.java:52)    at Server.main(Server.java:19)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry     at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
> ... 4 more
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

These are the jar files that I have included in my project.
[image]

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>booksharing2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>booksharing2</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>




    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5</version>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5</version>
        </dependency>





        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It has some problems:

[image]

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        " http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Connessione al database -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/booksharing</property>
        
        <!-- Credenziali -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">0000</property>
        
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory</property>
        
        <!--<property name="show_sql">true</property> -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- Entity -->
        <mapping class="database.CopiaDBWrapper" />
        <mapping class="database.LibroDBWrapper" />
        <mapping class="database.RecensioneDBWrapper" />
        <mapping class="database.UtenteRegistratoDBWrapper" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

With my hibernate.cfg.xml file, the pure Java project worked, so I don't think it has any problems.
I am unfamiliar with both Hibernate and Tomcat. So I have no idea what might be causing the error.
I tried various solutions given in other questions, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing these errors because you are trying to use a version that does not exist. Hibernate versions are usually of the format `MAJOR.MINOR.FIX.Final` so you should use `4.3.5.Final`